# Get all beans with qualifier that has a binding value

Tags: wildfly, cdi, weld

I have a custom qualifier in my appliation that can be used like:

```
@Person(name = "bob")
public class Bob implements IPerson { ... }
```

where the `name` value of the `Person` qualifier is binding. (Not annotated with `@Nonbinding`)

One part of my application needs to know all `Person` beans and another part of my application needs access to a specific `Person`

To access a specific `Person` I can use:

```
@Inject @Person(name = "bob")
IPerson bob;
```

But how can I get all Person beans? I can't use

```
@Inject @Person(name = "")
Instance<IPersion> people;
```

since `name` is binding. If i declare `name` as `@Nonbinding` the above code works but I'm not longer able to inject a specific Person via it's name.

I currently use the following method to get all `Person` beans:

```
@Inject @Any
private Instance<IPerson> people;
...
for (IPerson person : people) {
    if (hasPersonAnnotaion(person)) {...}
}
```

whereas `hasPersonAnnotaion()` programmatically checks the persons class for the `@Person` annotation. Is there a better way?

Comment: Hi, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging related to your tags and title

Answer (score 0):

In the current state of your code, `@Any` looks like the best bet.
With that you obviously need the filtering that you perform.

Though knowing your code will need all instances with given qualifier *and if the filtering is pricy (lots of instances without `@Person` qualifier?)*, you might want to add additional qualifier without binding value that will be on each `IPerson` - something like `@IsPerson`.
Then you could `@Inject @IsPerson Instance<IPerson> people` and no filtering is needed.

Note that additional qualifier won't give you headaches in terms of existing injection points (e.g. `@Inject @Person(name = "bob") IPerson bob;` will be still valid).

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. The second qualifier is a nice idea and in fact I already thought about using the `@Named` annotation as additional qualifier but this would just shift the problem, because then I need to check if both annotations are available on the instance.

Comment: You would have to make sure that whenever the `@Person` qualiflier is added, the new one is added as well. E.g. so that you know in runtime that whenever you get instance of `IPerson` which has `@Person` qualifier, it has the new one as well (and vice versa). I suppose you could even simply attach the new annotation to each new relevant `Iperson` bean via CDI extension.